# How to increase JSON variable length?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I am making a chart for a school website and it uses a JSON variable as data of the chart.

Each variable in the JSON array datasets is includes all the information for one line:

```
{
                    fillColor : "rgba(55, 171, 200, 1)",
                    strokeColor : document.getElementById('chosen-color').value,
                    pointColor : "rgba(220,55,220, 1)",
                    pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                    data : [
                        <?// Data
                        $values = getValues("btc_30");
                        for($i = 0; $i<sizeof($values); $i++){
                            print $values[$i];
                             if ($i != sizeof($values)-1){print ", ";}
                          }
                       ?>
                   ]
                }
```

Now I want to let a HTML form be able to add more lines to the chart, which means that the datasets JSON array need to be increased if a new line is added.
I have a JavaScript for it:

```
var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
        for(var x = 0; x<boxes.length; x++){
                if(boxes[x].checked == true){
                    data.datasets[x].fillColor = "rgba(55, 171, 200, 1)";
                    data.datasets[x].strokeColor = document.getElementById('chosen-color').value;
                    data.datasets[x].pointColor = "rgba(55, 171, 200, 1)";
                    data.datasets[x].data = [
                        <?// Data
                        $values = getValues("xrp_30");
                        for($i = 0; $i<sizeof($values); $i++){
                            print $values[$i];
                             if ($i != sizeof($values)-1){print ", ";}
                          }
                       ?>
                    ]
                }
        }
```

But it does not allow me to acces a datasets[x] that does not exists yet, so now my question is how do I increase the JSON array datasets ?

EDIT: I fixed it thanks to phill's, Chausser's and Wolfgang Stengel's awnswers. The nicest way to do it is:

```
var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
    for(var x = 0; x<boxes.length; x++){
            if(boxes[x].checked == true){
                data.datasets[x] = {
                    fillColor: "rgba(55, 171, 200, 1)",
                    strokeColor: document.getElementById('chosen-color').value,
                    pointColor: "rgba(55, 171, 200, 1)",
                    data: <?= json_encode(getValues('xrp_30')) ?>
                };
            }
    }
```

I didn't even know I could do this `<?= json_encode(getValues('xrp_30')) ?>`
... Guess I learned something else too :)

Comment: Create an empty object with `data.datasets[x]={};` before you access it.

Comment: <3 this was the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This perhaps

```
data.datasets[x] = {
    fillColor: "rgba(55, 171, 200, 1)",
    strokeColor: document.getElementById('chosen-color').value,
    pointColor: "rgba(55, 171, 200, 1)",
    data: <?= json_encode(getValues('xrp_30')) ?>
};
```

Comment: This works if the datasets[x] is previously created. (I start with only one line in the chart making the length of datasets 1).
I do not know how to increase datasets with 1 so I can create a new chart info varialbe.

Comment: @Krulvis You can add any index to a JavaScript array. It doesn't need to be set previously

Comment: The PHP code to string out the data for data: does work but when I get to the point where it's a x higher than the size of datasets I get this error:
http://i.imgur.com/hwGSvI0.png
This happens when datasets[x] doesn't exist yet.

Comment: @Krulvis And the code in that screenshot looks **nothing** like my answer

Comment: I only had to add this when I was trying to access undefined code: data.datasets[x]={}; -.-'
 Wolfgang Stengel gave me the right answer

Comment: @Krulvis Mine does exactly the same only it also sets your object properties within the declaration

Comment: Oké you're right, it's a bit more than was necessary but it would've made it nicer all together, I didn't know that json_encode() function at all.

Thanks anyways and sorry for doubting you :P

Answer (score 0):

Check that the dataset object exists if it doesnt create it then set the data. If the box isnt checked unset the data.

```
var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
for(var x = 0; x<boxes.length; x++){
    if(boxes[x].checked == true){
        if(data.datasets[x] == "undefined"){ 
            //Check that the dataset exists, create it if it doesnt.
            data.datasets[x]={};
        }
        data.datasets[x].fillColor = "rgba(55, 171, 200, 1)";
        data.datasets[x].strokeColor = document.getElementById('chosen-color').value;
        data.datasets[x].pointColor = "rgba(55, 171, 200, 1)";
        // php short code for echo "<?= ?>"
        // then use php's function json_encode to turn the array into a json object
        data.datasets[x].data = <?= json_encode(getValues("xrp_30")); ?>;

    }
    else{
        //Unset the dataset if the box isnt checked.
        data.datasets[x] = {};
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this, but I need to create it if it doesn't exists. And I do not know how to do this in the javaScript for loop

Comment: Looks to me like he loops over a set of checkboxes and sets values when they are checked. This would overwrite any previous values